# How can I set the power button behaivor of beagle bone black?

Tags: beagleboneblack, wakeup

I'm working on Beagle Bone Black, and I need to change the power button behaivor.

Img that I'm using:
*bone-debian-8.7-lxqt-4gb-armhf-2017-03-19-4gb.img*

As the documentation says, this button can wakeup is the module has in suspend mode.

> REF: BBONEBLK_SRM BeagleBone Black System Reference Manual Rev C.1
>
> 6.1.8.5 WAKEUP The WAKEUP signal from the TPS65217C is connected to the EXT_WAKEUP signal on the processor. This is used to wake up the
>   processor when it is in a sleep mode. When an event is detected by the
>   TPS65217C, such as the power button being pressed, it generates this
>   signal.

Anybody knows how can I change it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to change the power button behavior to what?

Comment: At this moment, if I press the power button the BBB proceed to shutdown. But, if the BBB is suspended, when I press the power button doesn't wake up. I need to change this behavior to wake up the module.

Comment: I checked with my BBB (bone-debian-8.10-lxqt-4gb-armhf-2018-01-01-4gb.img.xz) and it also doesn't work. I suggest you to post this issue on beaglebone google group. SO isn't the best place for beaglebone-specific quesitons

Comment: Thank you, I had done it, but nobody answers yet.